# Appear TableView when a view is touched

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have an application that is divided into 4 quadrants, each quadrant is a view. Each view I have to fill it with a graph, for which I am using Core-Plot. I want when you touch a view appear a tableviewcontroller, but I cant do it. I have researched, but all I get is the ViewController in full view.

The idea is like this:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=a9f400f6a1d61745&resid=A9F400F6A1D61745!414&parid=root

I can't put the image because is my first post.

How could implement?

This is not the only TableViewController, because choosing an option leads me to another table view and so on to the data. There are 4 levels.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create four navigation controller with the view controllers which manages the core plot view as root view controller. Than add the view property of the navigation controller to the main view (`[mainView addSubview: [navigationController1 view]`).

I don't know whether this works but I would try it this way.